# Sudoku GUI in Python with Tkinter - StringVar not updating

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, sudoku

I recently successfully wrote a recursive code that uses backtracking to solve a simple sudoku puzzle. I want to create it so that I solved the puzzle live, i.e with the numbers changing in real-time and wanted to do so using the tkinter module. I created a 9*9 board with each number as a particular label and stored the text of the label in a StringVar() so I could update it continuously. All the StringVars were stored in a 9*9 array(called textvars) so that they corresponded to the original sudoku board I wanted to solve, and I could thus use the row and column number to update the text. The following is the code for this part:

```
def main():
    textvars = []
    t1 = []
    board = [[3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0],
             [5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
             [0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0],
             [9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5],
             [0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0],
             [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4],
             [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0]]

    for i in range(9):
        t1 = []
        for j in range(9):
            txt = StringVar()
            if board[i][j]==0:
                txt.set('')
            else:
                txt.set(str(board[i][j]))
            Label(root,height = 2, width = 4, textvariable = txt, relief = "solid").grid(row = i, column = j)
            t1.append(txt)
        textvars.append(t1)

    solve_board(board, textvars)
```

These text variables and boards were passed to a solve_board() function which used backtracking and when updating the board, it updated the text alongside using the .set() function, like so:

```
def solve_board(board,textvars):

        for rowno in range(9):

            for colno in range(9):

                if board[rowno][colno] == 0:
                    for i in range(1,10):

                        if (is_valid(board,rowno,colno,i)):
                            board[rowno][colno]=i
                            textvars[rowno][colno].set(str(i))
                            solve_board(board,textvars)
                            board[rowno][colno]=0
                            textvars[rowno][colno].set('')
                    return False

        print (np.matrix(board))
```

All the bits that are not gui or tkinter related work perfectly, although they were typed in a hurry leading to less than optimal code.

When this code is run, the board displayed on the tkinter window is the unsolved board while the board being printed is fully solved.

I hope you could help me figure out as to why this code is not working and I have attached the rest of the code, an is_valid function and a main one below for further reference. Thank you.

```
def is_valid(b,r,c,n): #check if number insertion is valid
    if n in b[r]: #if in row
        return False
    for x in range(0,9):
        if n == b[x][c]: #check for column
            return False
    sr = r - r%3
    sc = c - c%3
    for x in range(sr,sr+3):
        for y in range(sc,sc+3):
            if b[x][y]==n:
                return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Sudoku")

    main()
    root.mainloop()
```

EDIT:

The code:

```
board[rowno][colno]=0
textvars[rowno][colno].set('')
```

This is used to reflect the backtracking process, i.e if a choice made is incorrect, the program goes back to the last time it made a choice and it resets the choice by setting it to 0. Setting the text to '' is simply to reflect the reset made my the program in the tkinter window.

Comment: I also tried storing all the labels in another array and the output was the same.

Comment: I think you need to put `t1 = []` before `for j in range(9)`.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad! I forgot to put that - it fixes the issue with the top row disappearing from the output but the labels still do not update in the tkinter window, and the displayed board remains unsolved while the board I print is solved!

Comment: I think it is because you have call `textvars[rowno][colno].set('')` at the end of the inner `if` block.  Try removing that line.

Comment: It is better to update those `StringVar` at the end of `solve_board()` instead.

Comment: While that does display all the characters, it displays an incorrect solution of the board as the labels in the displayed board do not backtrack!

Comment: Do what I said in my last comment.  Don't update those StringVar in the if block.

Comment: ***`textvars[rowno][colno].set('')`***: [Edit] your question and explain in detail, **why** do you reset the solved value afterwards?

Comment: Wait I can't exactly understand what you are referring to, would it be possible for you to retype that bit in the form of code? That would help me immensely, thank you!

Comment: If I update StringVar at the end of the solve_board function won't it just update the window once with the solved solution and won't update it continuously while solving the board as it only exits the block if there are no blank spaces right? It would be great if you could write that snippet of code and share it with me! Thank you!

Comment: Even though you set the StringVar in the if block, you won't see the result because `mainloop()` is not executed yet.  As I don't fully understand the solving logic, but if you print some messages in the for loop, you will find that the recursion of `solve_board()` is not finished after the first `print(np...)` which I think is the final solution.  That means  the final solution will be overwritten by the reset of `board` and `StringVar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to return `True` at the end of `solve_board()` function.  Also return at once if `solve_board()` return `True` in the if block.

Since `mainloop()` is not executed when `solve_board()` is running, therefore if you want to see the update during solving, you need to call `root.update()` after setting the StringVar:

```
def solve_board(board, textvars):
    for rowno in range(9):
        for colno in range(9):
            if board[rowno][colno] == 0:
                for i in range(1, 10):
                    if is_valid(board, rowno, colno, i):
                        board[rowno][colno] = i
                        textvars[rowno][colno].set(str(i))
                        root.update()
                        if solve_board(board, textvars):
                            return True
                        board[rowno][colno] = 0
                        textvars[rowno][colno].set('')
                        root.update()
                return False
    print(np.matrix(board))
    return True
```

Comment: That works great! I think the missing update was messing my code up, thank you so much!